# How to create instance of the unkown type?

Tags: java

I have a couple of functions which requires exact argument type (aka `T`):

```
private <T> void doWork1(T _obj) {...}
private <T> void doWork2(T _obj) {...}
private <T> void doWork3(T _obj) {...}
```

I use them like this and it works fine:

```
public void parse(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case 1: {
            Integer obj = new Integer(1);
            doWork1(obj);
            doWork2(obj);
            doWork3(obj);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            Double obj = new Double(2);
            doWork1(obj);
            doWork2(obj);
            doWork3(obj);
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            CustomClass obj = new CustomClass();
            doWork1(obj);
            doWork2(obj);
            doWork3(obj);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to make the code more concise i.e.

```
public void parse(int id) {
    UnknownType obj;
    switch (id) {
        case 1: {
            obj = new Integer(1);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            obj = new Double(2);
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            obj = new CustomClass();
            break;
        }
    }
    doWork1(obj);
    doWork2(obj);
    doWork3(obj);
}
```

If so what should I put instead of `UnknownType`?
**Edit:**
1) I used `Integer` and `Double` as a simplified example. In my actual code I use custom classes.
2) I need to know exact type (class) in my `doWork` functions so I can't use `Object`
Thanks in advance

Comment: If doWork1 accepts object, use Object. Your question depends on how the parameters of doWork1 are structured (overloaded, or just one function).

Comment: @JFMeier it does, since `T` is unbounded.

Comment: If you need to know the exact type in the method, you need to pass `Class<T>` as a parameter to the method.

Comment: @AndyTurner, okey, and what about `UnknownType` in this situation?

Comment: @StephanLeila it can still be either `Number` or `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Number` or `Object`, which are both common supertypes of `Integer` and `Double`.

---

However, the generics are unnecessary:

```
private <T> void doWork1(T _obj) {...}
```

is identical to

```
private void doWork1(Object _obj) {...}
```

after erasure.

The only point of having a type variable for an input parameter is if:

- You need to indicate that the generics of another input parameter need to be related, e.g. you are passing `T _obj` and `List<T> _list`.

  Note that you don't need a generic type for `T _obj1` and `T _obj2`, though - that degenerates to the upper bound of `T` (e.g. `Object`);
- If you need it to be related to the return type:

  ```
  <T> T doWork1(T _obj) { ... }
  ```

You don't need either case here, so just remove the unnecessary complication.

Comment: thanks for clarifications. Yep, `Object` will do, many thanks

Answer (score 4):

User the type `Number` for your `obj`. `Integer` and `Double` both extend this type.

> The abstract class {@code Number} is the superclass of platform 
>   classes representing numeric values that are convertible to the 
>   primitive types {@code byte}, {@code double}, {@code float}, {@code 
>   int}, {@code long}, and {@code short}.

```
public void parse(int id)
{
    Number obj = null;
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            obj = new Integer(1);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            obj = new Double(2);
            break;
        }
    }
    doWork1(obj);
    doWork2(obj);
    doWork3(obj);
}
```

If you do not want to be this concrete, you can always use `Object`.

Comment: @StephanLeila How do you know the type inside `doWork` if you use your first example?