# Having "T" vs "Object" as method argument to accept parameter?

Tags: java, generics

I want to make have a method which accepts generic argument. I want to know which practice is better from the listed ones:

1.`void someMethod(T object)`
OR
2. `void someMethod(Object object)`

Also what are the advantages of the each of the above?

Comment: `void someMethod(T object)` will create generic object for any particular type where as `void someMethod(Object object)` may cause ambugity

Comment: **note** : both are different

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38475261/3788176). In particular, I think the "The only point of having a type variable for an input parameter is if:" is relevant to your question here.

Answer (score 0):

`void someMethod(T object)` is not a generic method (you don't have a `<T> void someMethod(T object)`), so it must be in some generic class which has a type parameter `T`, and the `T` here refers to that `T`. `YourClass<Foo>.someMethod()` will only accept an argument of type `Foo`.

On the other hand, if it were declared as `void someMethod(Object object)`, then the method would always accept a reference of any type, i.e. `YourClass<Foo>.someMethod()` will only accept an argument of any reference type.