# Why are JUnit assert methods not generic in Java?

Tags: java, generics, junit

I am using JUnit 4.12. The assert methods are not generic in nature. For instance, assertEquals method looks like:

```
static public void assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {..}
```

Why is it not like?

```
static public <T> void assertEquals(T expected, T actual) {..}
```

I felt need for generic method declaration for better compile time checking and IDE auto completion.

Comment: Downvoters, please provide the reason.

Comment: What do you thing the generics give you there? See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38475261/3788176) which explains why it would be redundant.

Comment: @AndyTurner So that I do not accidentally compare objects of two different types, which is anyway invalid. IDE will give better suggestions as to what arguments can be passed in the method, instead of showing list of all the existing objects in the scope.

Comment: Try writing your own method, using generics, and see just how much type safety it gives you.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry, I do not get your point. After passing the first argument, the IDE does suggest the valid objects which can be passed as second argument. What's the harm in that?

Comment: I mean literally try implementing it. Write a trivial method in your class `<T> void assertEquals(T a, T b) {}`, and see if the compiler prevents you from calling it with "incompatible" arguments. (Spoiler: it won't).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a generic method like this:

```
<T> void assertEquals(T expected, T actual) { /* ... */ }
```

gives you no type safety to avoid comparing unlike types: you can pass in anything to this method, since `T` degenerates to its upper bound, `Object`:

```
assertEquals("string", 0);  // Compiles fine, even though they can't be equal.
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/mqLksx)

And nor can you use any methods on `expected` and `actual` that aren't found on `Object`. So, `T` is basically just `Object`.

As such, adding generics is just over-complicating the implementation.

---

Now, you could define a class like this:

```
class GenericAssert<T> {
  void assertEquals(T expected, T actual) { /* ... */ }
}
```

and you could use this like:

```
new GenericAssert<String>().assertEquals("string", 0);  // Compiler error.
```

because you've now placed a tighter upper bound on the acceptable parameters of `assertEquals`, at class level.

But this just feels a bit awkward.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented it and I see what you are telling is right. I need to understand generics better.

Comment: GenericAssert can solve my purpose. But I do see that it will make the test case messier, as I'll need different GenericAsset object for different type of objects in contrast to using the clean static methods as declared in JUnit. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Alternatively, you could write a `checkedAssertEquals(Object, Object)` method, which checked that the arguments are compatible, then invoked `Assert.assertEquals`. It wouldn't fail at compile time, but it'd fail once the test runs, which isn't so bad.

Comment: Of course, `assertEquals` on incompatible types would always fail anyway.

Comment: Right, assertEquals anyway fails with incompatible types. So, using JUnit as it is seems the right option as test case fails even if I make type mistakes in the test case itself.

Answer (score 4):

You want to look [**assertThat**](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/matchers-and-assertthat) and the Hamcrest matchers; as assertThat actually works with generics:

```
assertThat(String reason, T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher)
```

So:

```
assertEquals("abc", 123);
```

compiles, but fails; whereas

```
assertThat(123, is("abc"));
```

won't even compile!

And I am not even mentioning that asserThat calls are much better to read; and give much better information when they fail. You can even use them to compare maps, sets, whatever.

Long story short: there is only one assert that anybody needs - **assertThat** that is!

Comment: Thanks. I tried using this but its compiling without any error!

Comment: Well, my compiler gives me: `The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (String, Matcher<Integer>)` ... no idea what you were doing in order to not hit an error there.

Comment: Well, I used org.junit.Assert.assertThat and org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is, and it doesn't give any compile time error.

Comment: Very strange. Which version of JUnit / hamcrest are you using?

Comment: JUnit is 4.12 and I am on Java 8 if that matters.

Comment: Things get weirder and weirder here. What IDE/compiler are you using? Can you like "press F3" on those calls, and check the "source" of them?

Comment: @Anmol I don't think that turning my answer into another question is really a good idea. Answers are answers; questions are questions. So, the better option my eyes: remove the parts you added to my answer, and put them into a new question. It is perfectly fair to ask why that one line doesn't give you a compile error. Final note: I am using eclipse neon; but I would rather doubt that this is the problem. But maybe you want to give it a try. Would like to approve your edits, but i am currently blocked from accepting reviews ;-(

Comment: No worries. I'll try finding the problem with my code/compiler/IDE and post a new question if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[GhostCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38800772/10963206) answer works for Java 7, but it doesn't work for Java 8+

```
assertThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher)
```

`? super T` in `Matcher<? super T>` means that we can match object of type `T` with any object with such type that it's a parent of type `T`. Thanks to this we can write the next code:

```
Integer actual = 5;
Object expected = 5;
assertThat(actual, is(expected));
```

But it also means you can write the next code which will be compiled and fail only in runtime:

```
Integer actual = 5;
String expected = "5";
assertThat(actual, is(expected));
```

Anyway in Java 7 the next examples will not compile:

```
assertThat(123, is("123"));
assertThat(Collections.singletonList(1), is(Collections.emptyList()));
```

We have to manually specify the type:

```
assertThat(123, CoreMatchers.<Object>is("123"));
assertThat(Collections.singletonList(1), is(Collections.<Integer>emptyList()));
```

Java 8 introduced Lambda expressions and they made improvements for type inference (shortly type inference can be made using the context of method invocation) to reduce number of times when we have to manually specify generic type. Because of this the previous example will compile successfully in Java 8:

```
assertThat(123, is("123"));
assertThat(Collections.singletonList(1), is(Collections.emptyList()));
```

For Java 8+ if you want to avoid the code to be compiled just specify the type manually:

```
assertThat(123, CoreMatchers.<Integer>("123")); // will not compile
```