# Why does this generic code in java compile?

Tags: java

```
public static <T> T foo(T x, T x2) {
    return (T) (x + "   " + x2);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(foo(33, "232"));
}
```

I know T gets to be of the type that is passed in the parameter.
But here there are two types.
Which one of them is T?

and why the compiler doesn't force me to have the parameters of same type when I call foo?

Comment: It's legal because `T` can be `Object`, so you can pass the method any two objects. (`32` can be an `Integer` rather than an `int` in this case.)

Comment: And the upper bound of `T` is `Object`, so in the compiled code, the cast `(T)` is `(Object)`, which is valid, because `String` is an `Object`.

Comment: Also to add on the comments, that´s the reason why you never want to make use of undbound types(leaving out the generics), as basicly every combination of classes is valid due to it. When you do it, you might find yourself in a sitatation where `ClassCastExceptions` are the usual result of trying to work with the raw types

Comment: @KevinEsche by "raw" do you mean "unbounded"? If so, I would say that, because "raw" means something specific in the context of generics.

Comment: The compiler _does_ give you an "Unchecked cast from String to T" warning in `foo()`, essentially telling that you shouldn't do this.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA inferred type `java.io.Serializable` with such arguments..

Comment: @cybersoft yeah, it would be for all compilers, because both `String` and `Integer` are `Serializable`, which is more specific than `Object`. But the point is that `T` doesn't mean "the same type", it means "some common type".

Comment: This question is sort-of related: [Why are JUnit assert methods not generic in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787083/why-are-junit-assert-methods-not-generic-in-java)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's legal because `Integer` and `String` have a common base type. `T` can be `Object`, so `foo(T, T)` will accept any two objects. `32` can be autoboxed to an `Integer`, which is a kind of `Object`. `"232"` is a `String`, which is a kind of `Object`.

(As pointed out by comments, for `Integer` and `String`, there is a closer common base-type, `Serializable`; but the principle is the same whichever base type the compiler resolves `T` to.)

Comment: Can you describe what happens in this line: `return (T) (x + "   " + x2)`? Is it equivalent to `return (Object) (x.toString() + "   " + x2.toString())`? If so, what happens in the casting, if it casts a string to object then how this string is retrieved in the printing?

Comment: @TheLogicGuy If you try and add any object to a string, it be converted using `toString()`. If you try and print any object, it will convert be converted to a String using `toString()`. (If your object is a string, `toString()` just returns `this`.)

Answer (score 5):

```
public static <T> T foo(T x, T x2) {
    return (T) (x + "   " + x2);
}
```

It should be noted that whilst this compiles, it can fail at runtime:

```
int f = foo(1, 2);
```

will fail [<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/wRGhku), because the method returns a `String`, not an `Integer`.

It *compiles*, though, because type erasure means that `T` is rewritten to the upper bound, namely `Object`. So:

```
public static Object foo(Object x, Object x2) {
  return (Object) (x + "   " + x2);
}
```

This is fine, because the result is a `String`, which is a subtype of `Object`.

I guess this is just a case where the generics model it waiting to catch you out. This is why I would avoid mixing generics and explicit casting.

Comment: int f = foo(1, 2); will not compile..

Comment: @Brovoker why not?

Comment: Because no instance of type variable exist so that T conforms to int

Comment: @Brovoker autoboxing, dear chap. Never noticed that you can add an `int` to a `List<Integer>`? [It compiles](http://ideone.com/wRGhku).

Comment: In your link you do foo(1, 2) , try foo(1, "two")

Comment: ...which does something different to the point I'm illustrating here.

Comment: The question refers to using 2 different types as arguments

Comment: @Brovoker the question is vague as to what it is asking why it compiles. khelwood's answer explains why the method invocation compiles; I'm explaining why the method compiles, but pointing out that it is not type safe.

Comment: Sorry I missread 1, 2 for 1, "2"

Comment: @Brovoker Well then these comments can be cleaned up :D.